# PostgreSQL command psql not found, trouble adding to $PATH

Tags: postgresql, path, bash

I am trying to add PostgreSQL to my $PATH variable. I tried this to see where `psql` is

```
whereis psql
```

To which I got a null response. I do have the PostgreSQL.app installed so I clicked on "Open psql" from the GUI and it prompted the Terminal to open and display:

```
 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql; exit;
```

So I tried to add the above to the `$PATH` variable in my `~/.bash_profile` (which may have its own problems since I don't know if you can add paths with .app extensions to the $PATH) but when I restart my Terminal and do `echo $PATH | grep Postgres.app` I get nothin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach to take help isolate problems you may have.

### Step 1: See if you can add PostgreSQL to your PATH without using Bash dot files.

```
$ export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH;
$ which psql
```

*If this works...*

### Step 2: Verify that `~\.bash_profile` is being sourced when a new user session is started.

**Add the following to the end of your `~/.bash_profile`:**

```
echo "From bash_profile.";
```

Now restart `Terminal.app` or `iTerm` and see if that message appears about your prompt.

*If this works...*

### Step 3: Add PATH to `~/.bash_profile`.

In `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH;
```

Restart your terminal and run:

```
$ which psql
```

If you're not seeing:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
```

Then it might be time to scrap trying to install PostgreSQL as a Mac package and use Homebrew.

**NOTE**: It's `psql` and NOT `pgsql`.

Comment: do I need to restart Terminal in between setting the variable and the `whereis` command? Is there a command to reset Terminal that is more legit than just closing and opening Terminal.app?

Comment: No, don't restart the terminal in **Step 1**.  After you run the export cmd, what does `echo $PATH;` return?

Comment: It returns: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin: ... etc. So it adds it to the $PATH

Comment: Ah! So when I write `where is psql` I get the following: `is not found
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql`

Comment: I am still getting stuck at **Step 2**.

Comment: Actually you should `which`.  Updated my answer.

Comment: In that case I am stuck at **Step 1** as `which psql` returns a blank line

Comment: I think it's Homebrew time :). is it just `brew install postgresql` ?

Comment: What happens when you type `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql;`?  Does `psql` run?

Comment: Wish I could be of more help.  The official install docs for Postgres.app are very similar to my answer http://postgresapp.com/documentation/ but I'm stumped.  Good luck!

Comment: well in anyways the Homebrew approach works beautifully. thank you for all yr help!

Comment: I don't know why I ever even tried a reg mac package instead of just using brew..

Silly me :/

Answer (score 1):

From the Postgres [documentation page:](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html)

> sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

restart your terminal and you will have it in your path.