# Vagrant -bash: psql: command not found on Windows - Git Bash

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, psql

I'm trying to run `psql` command after running `vagrant up` command then `vagrant ssh` command

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-75-generic i686)

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates

Last login: Sat Jun 17 02:55:00 2017 from 10.0.2.2

vagrant@vagrant:~$ psql
-bash: psql: command not found
```

`

I tried these solutions:

[psql: command not found Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155219/psql-command-not-found-mac)

[PostgreSQL command psql not found, trouble adding to $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701114/postgresql-command-psql-not-found-trouble-adding-to-path)

With `locate psql` command to put my own PATH

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psql
```

But still `psql` not found

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install psql on the VM, for this you need to install `postgresql` and `postgresql-contrib` packages as follow:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-75-generic i686)

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates

Last login: Sat Jun 17 02:55:00 2017 from 10.0.2.2

vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt-get update
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```